# C string alteration

Tags: c, string

So, I got to a point where I have a string with words and punctuation marks ( a full sentence to be exact). I wanted to change one word in that sentence. The number of letters of the new word may not be the exact with the previous one. I also have a 2-d matrix with the words of the sentence changed now so that it has the new word instead of the old one. So I managed to trade all words in my original string with a `*` and keep the punctuation marks so that I can change the `*` with the words of the altered 2-d matrix and keep the punctuation marks. So my real question is how can I change the `*` of the string with whole words and then add the punctuation marks where needed.

```
Example:
Original string: HELLO PEOPLE. HELLO WORLD. HOW ARE YOU TODAY?
Word for change: WORLD --> MAN
String with '*': * *. * *.* * * *?
Result I want: HELLO PEOPLE. HELLO MAN. HOW ARE YOU TODAY?
```

I tried this (with `text3` string with'*' and text 4 the result I want):

```
l1=0;sum3=0;
for (k=0;k<sum2;k++){
    if (text3[k]=='*'){
        strcpy(&text4[sum3],textb1[l1]);
        l1++;
        sum3=sum3+strlen(textb1[l1]);
    }
    else {
        text4[sum3]=text3[k];
        sum3++;
    }
}
printf("%s\n",text4);
```

But I only manage to get the first HELLO printed.

Comment: You'll have to allocate sufficient space for the new string if the new string will be longer than the old one.

Comment: Instead of replacing the words with `*`, replace them with `%s` and use `sprintf()`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I made both strings: char text3[1000]={0},text4[1000]={0} so I dont think there is a problem with memory space

Comment: What's the purpose of the *'s? The usual way of doing this would be to find the index of the start of the word to be changed, and its length. Copy over the first part, copy in the new word, copy over the remainder. If you want to do it "in place", you would move the remainder left or right, and then overwrite the word.

Comment: @clcto: Please don't do that. Or if you do be *VERY CAREFUL* and escape any % you find in the original string. There is an entire class of C language security bugs called "Format string attacks."

Comment: @ZanLynx he is creating that string ... so its not really an attack if he does it. Edit: I guess he has to be careful when he creates that string though.

Comment: @clcto can you please give me an example of sprintf() cause im not really familiar with this function

Comment: @clcto: It is very easy to put code inside a function and forget how it works and then pass an outside value to that function. People should never start to think that making their own format string is a safe thing to do.

Comment: @user3634157: On Linux, BSD or MacOS type "man sprintf". For Windows learn to use and love MSDN.

Comment: What about: pushing each *word* and all *punctuation* on a stack -- change word in the stack -- rebuild string?

Answer (score 0):

A few bugs:

```
l1=0;sum3=0;
for (k=0;k<sum2;k++){
    if (text3[k]=='*'){
        strcpy(&text4[sum3],textb1[l1]);
        /*l1++; */  /* You are incrementing the wrong length I think.... */
        sum3=sum3+strlen(textb1[l1]);
        l1++;  
    }
    else {
        text4[sum3]=text3[k];
        sum3++;
    }
}
text4[sum3] = 0;   /* Null terminate */
printf("%s\n",text4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full program, based on my "stack" idea, to demonstrate:

1. split then store words on spaces and punctuation;
2. store into a basic stack;
3. print out with spaces added where needed;
4. output `new` word whenever `old` word was in input.

The latter replaces *every* occurrence of `old` with `new`, as it was not specified the replacement should only occur once. Overflow handling of `stack` and memory cleanup omitted for clarity.

#### Pro

Spaces are always concatenated into one single space.

Easily adjustable for other scenarios.

#### Con

Spaces are always concatenated into one single space.

It only checks for *alphanumerics* and a basic punctuation set.

Handling of punctuation is very basic. For instance, initially I added `()` to `punct` as well, but these need further adjustments in the output routine that insert spaces. If necessary, you could, for instance, make `stack` a struct and add a `spaceAfter` member and save where the original spaces occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *stack[256];
int stack_depth = 0;

const char *punct = ".,:;!?";

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *ptr, *find, *change;
    int i;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        ptr = strrchr (argv[0], '/');
        if (!ptr)
            ptr = strrchr (argv[0], '\\');
        if (ptr)
            ptr++;
        else
            ptr = argv[0];
        printf ("usage: %s \"original string\" \"original --> new\"\n", ptr);
        return 0;
    }

    ptr = argv[1];

    while (*ptr)
    {
        while (*ptr == ' ')
            ptr++;

        i = 0;
        while (ptr[i])
        {
        /*  do not store spaces */
            if (ptr[i] == ' ')
                break;
        /*  stop on punctuation */
            if (strchr (punct, ptr[i]))
                break;
            i++;
        }
        if (i)
        {
            stack[stack_depth] = malloc(i+1);
            if (stack[stack_depth] == NULL)
            {
                printf ("oh wow, out of memory\n");
                return -1;
            }
            strncpy (stack[stack_depth], ptr, i);
            stack[stack_depth][i] = 0;
            stack_depth++;
            ptr += i;
        }
        if (*ptr && strchr (punct, *ptr))
        {
            i = 0;
            while (ptr[i] && strchr (punct, ptr[i]))
                i++;
            stack[stack_depth] = malloc(i+1);
            if (stack[stack_depth] == NULL)
            {
                printf ("oh wow, out of memory\n");
                return -1;
            }
            strncpy (stack[stack_depth], ptr, i);
            stack[stack_depth][i] = 0;
            stack_depth++;
            ptr += i;
        }
    }

    printf ("Original string: ");
    for (i=0; i<stack_depth; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && !strchr (punct, stack[i][0]))
            printf (" ");
        printf ("%s", stack[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    /* fetch change words */
    ptr = strstr (argv[2], " --> ");
    if (!ptr)
    {
        printf ("bad syntax!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* fetch the length of 'find' */
    i = ptr-argv[2];
    find = malloc (i+1);
    strncpy (find, argv[2], i);
    find[i] = 0;

    /* fetch the length of 'change' */
    /* this is the 5 characters ' --> ' after start */
    ptr += 5;
    i = strlen(ptr);
    change = malloc (i+1);
    strncpy (change, ptr, i);
    change[i] = 0;

    printf ("Word for change: %s --> %s\n", find, change);

    printf ("Result: ");

    for (i=0; i<stack_depth; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && !strchr (punct, stack[i][0]))
            printf (" ");
        if (strcmp (stack[i], find))
            printf ("%s", stack[i]);
        else
            printf ("%s", change);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Test run:

```
replace "HELLO PEOPLE. HELLO WORLD. HOW ARE YOU TODAY?" "WORLD --> MAN"

Original string: HELLO PEOPLE. HELLO WORLD. HOW ARE YOU TODAY?
Word for change: WORLD --> MAN
Result: HELLO PEOPLE. HELLO MAN. HOW ARE YOU TODAY?
```